# Building a Table of Data with an Array of Arrays

Tags: php

I have an Array of Arrays and Want to create a Tabular data layout. This is not the exact code, as how their generated is quite the cluster (Coming from COBOL interaction) but this should give me enough to make it work if someone can think of a clean way to code this.

```
array(
    Array(847.0, 97010, 11)
    Array(847.0, 97012, 10)
    Array(847.1, 97010, 08)
    Array(847.1, 97012, 14)
)
```

So I want to put these into a Table that looks something like

```
          97010    97012
    847.0   11      10
    847.1   08      14
```

The first 2 elements of the arrays will always be the two axis and the 3rd the contents of the table.

Any Suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table = array();
$columns = array();

// copy the array (x, y, value) into a table
// keeping track of the unique column names as we go
foreach ($dataSet as $point) {
    // provided sample data used floats, ensure it is a string
    $x = strval($point[0]);
    $y = strval($point[1]);
    $data = $point[2];

    if (!isset($table[$x])) {
      $table[$x] = array();
    }

   $table[$x][$y] = $data;
   // quick and dirty style 'unique on insert'
   $columns[$y] = true;
}

// switch the column names from title => true to just titles
$columns = array_flip($columns);

// Display the table
echo '<table>';

// Header row
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
foreach ($columns as $columnTitle) {
    echo '<th>' . $columnTitle . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// Bulk of the table
foreach ($table as $rowTitle => $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>' . $rowTitle . '</th>';
    foreach ($columns as $columnTitle => $junk) {
        if (isset($row[$columnTitle]) {
            echo '<td>' . $row[$columnTitle] . '</td>';
        } else {
            // Handle sparse tables gracefully.
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood:

```
$arr[847.0][97010] = '11';
$arr[847.0][97012] = '10';
$arr[847.1][97010] = '08';
$arr[847.1][97012] = '14';
```

And you may create a table:

```
$result = "<table>";
foreach($arr as $row_key => $row) {
    $result .= "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column_key => $data) {
         $result .= "<td>".$data."</td>";
    }
    $result .= "</tr>";
}
$result .= "</table>";
echo $result;
```